# swift core data crash after adding attributes to an entity

Tags: core-data, swift

I have an entity in my data model, after I added an additional entity the app crashes when i try to acces it.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity");
var results=context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil);
```

Even if there is no items stored in it, it still crashes. If i delete the app and try again   it does not crash.

Crash message : "reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store""

Comment: Reset your simulator

Comment: there must be another way to do it

Comment: Lookup "Lightweight Migration" in the Core Data docs or here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Solved the problem by creating a new data model

Answer (score 2):

Every time you change the database model you **must** reset the iOS simulator as it has an old version of the database.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes deleting all files in  Library/Developer/Xcode do the job ..